# How to remove EditSettings button from filter cell in DevExpress DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I have the following column in my DevExpress datagrid:

```
             <dxg:GridColumn Width="Auto"
                            AllowEditing="False"
                            AutoFilterCondition="Equals"
                            FieldName="Name"
                            Header="Name"
                            ShowInColumnChooser="False"
                            SortOrder="Ascending"
                            VisibleIndex="0">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:ButtonEditSettings AllowDefaultButton="False">
                        <dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
                            <cm:ButtonInfo Content="X" Tag="RemoveItem" />
                        </dxe:ButtonEditSettings.Buttons>
                    </dxe:ButtonEditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

It looks okay in the rows, but it also appear in the *filter cell* of that column, and that could cause problems.

[image]

How could I remove it from the filter cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it [turned out](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T250524), I've been using the wrong approach.

You have to use ***CellTemplate*** instead of the EditSettings:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <dxe:ButtonEdit Name="PART_Editor" AllowDefaultButton="False">
            <dxe:ButtonEdit.Buttons>
                <dxe:ButtonInfo Content="X"/>
            </dxe:ButtonEdit.Buttons>
        </dxe:ButtonEdit>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```